# How to move a hyphenated string of numbers to another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Column A looks like this:

[image: The number string at the end of the cell]

I need to get all of the numbers with the hyphen and dots moved over to the next column.  The colon is unimportant.

With this:

```
=-LOOKUP(0,-RIGHT(A1,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}))
```

I can get varying lengths of numbers, but only up to the hyphen.

When I use:

```
=RIGHT(A1,12)
```

It will include the other characters, but there's not always 12 numbers. They are between 9 and 12.

So how can I get everything from the colon forward into the next column. 
P.S. these numbers are at the end of a path so there is another colon at the beginning of the cell "C:\"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just got smart and found a simple solution.  Rather than creating a formula (which I'd rather do, but am short on time) I just copied all of Column A into Column B.  Then I used find and replace with find set as *: and replace being empty.  This removed everything from the beginning of the path up to and including the final ":".  Would still be nice to then remove the numbers from Col A but this will do for now.